# ng2-dragula and dynamic form no sync directly

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-dragula

I have a form generated dynamically by the user:

```
  // this._fb is a FormBuilder
  ngOnInit():void {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
      message: this._fb.array([
      ])
    });
```

the json generated is something like

```
{
  "message": [
    {
      "type": 1,
      "value": "first message",
    },
    {
      "type": 1,
      "value": "second message",
    }
  ]
}
```

I have added the ng2-dragula directive in order to change the messages order

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formArrayName="message">
    <div [dragula]='"bag-one"' [dragulaModel]='myForm.controls.message.controls'>
      <div *ngFor="let c of myForm.controls.message.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default" >
        <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
          <label>value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="value">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The drag function is working nicely, however when I'm displaying the json of my form, it's still the old order, except if I start to change the content of a field. I that case the form is updated.

Comment: Just a quick guess: `[dragulaModel]='myForm.controls.message.controls'` is one way binding. Can you use the two way binding here or an event to update your model?

Comment: I'm quite new to angular2 what do you mean by two way binding use `[(ngModel)]` ? 
What is strange is that when I'm starting to edit a field, everything change to the correct order

Answer (score 5):

So I have found a solution, not sure it's the best and I'm quite new to angular but at least it's working.

So I figure-out that I need to find a way to emit an event from the form.

In my form I have actually a value "order" corresponding to the id in the list so I have done the following:

```
    _dragulaService.dropModel.subscribe((value:any) => {
      console.log(value);
      this.onDropModel(value.slice(1));
    });
  }

   private onDropModel(args:any):void {
     for (let i = 0; i < (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('message')).length; ++i) {
        (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('message')).at(i).patchValue("order", i);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean angular 16 solution here:

```
this.dragulaService.dropModel('placeholder-sections').subscribe((value:any) => {
  const placeholderSections = this.getPlaceholderSections();
  // Dragula provides the source and target index, and we can use these to just swap out the indexes in the actual FormArray
  placeholderSections.removeAt(value.sourceIndex);
  placeholderSections.insert(value.targetIndex, value.item);
});

getPlaceholderSections(): FormArray {
    return this.promptEditor.get('placeholderSections') as FormArray;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div formArrayName="placeholderSections" dragula="placeholder-sections" [(dragulaModel)]="this.getPlaceholderSections().controls">
    <div *ngFor="let placeHolderSection of this.getPlaceholderSections().controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]=i>
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

You could also add some backend api call to the

> this.dragulaService.dropModel('placeholder-sections').subscribe

section, to save the order at the same time.